# Show/hide element on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I got table like this:

```
<tr>
    <td class="title">Title</td>
    <td class="body">Body</td>
    <td class="any">Any text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="title">Title</td>
    <td class="body">Body</td>
    <td class="any">Any text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="title">Title</td>
    <td class="body">Body</td>
    <td class="any">Any text</td>
</tr>
```

I'm using this script to hide/show td="body"

```
$('.title').append("<button class='moredrop'>&darr;</button>");
$(".moredrop").click(function(){
    $(".body").toggle();
```

It shows and hides all td's in table. I want it to hide/show only this td like here:

```
     $("tr").toggle(
    function(){$(".body",this).css("display","block");},
    function(){$(".body",this).css("display","none");});
```

But on button click. Any ideas?

Comment: where is ".moredrop" in relation to the ".body"?

Comment: I didn't know how to relate them, so i asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search the containing TR and then go to the specific .body

```
$('.moredrop').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.body').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.title').append("<button class='moredrop'>&darr;</button>");
    $('tr').on('click','.moredrop',function(){
            $(this).parents('tr').children('.body').toggle();
    });
});
```

Here is the working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jzutm/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.moredrop').click(function(){
    $('td.body').toggle();
});
```